# How to access Django Model field value?

Tags: python, django

The following html code fails to switch between "Bookmark" and "Unbookmarked" if there is more than 1 video being bookmarked with the same user.

How can I changed the following **if loop** to check if this specific user has bookmarked this specific video rather than a user having a bookmarked video in general ?

```
<td>
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'view:favourite' details.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden'>
        {% if user.fav_videos.exists %}
            <button type='submit'>UnBookmark</button>
        {% else %}
            <button type='submit'>Bookmark</button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</td>
```

The **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="fav_videos", blank=True)
```

The **urls.py**

```
path('favourite_post/<int:fav_id>', views.favourite_post, name='favourite_post')
```

The **views.py**

```
def favourite_post(request, fav_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=fav_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.favourite.remove(request.user)

        else:
            post.favourite.add(request.user)

        # Rest code
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detailview', args=(fav_id,)))
```

The **detailed** class in the views.py

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    context_object_name = "details"
    model = Post
    template_name = "detail.html"
```

**Comment on answers:**
Both @Daniel and @andreihondrari works fine, one is more efficient than the other.

Comment: Where is "this specific video" in your template code?

Comment: You need to show your models.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry about that. I updated

Comment: Thanks, but the view you need to show is the detailview, not favourite_post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a template tag to query each video and find if the user is included in the users who favourited it, but that's not very efficient. It's probably much easier to get a list of the user's favourites in one go and pass it to the template:

```
favourite_ids = request.user.fav_videos.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

and in the template:

```
{% if detail.id in favourite_ids %}
```

Comment: 1 query versus n queries, nice one.

Comment: @Daniel How do I add this correctly under the favourite post ? :)

Comment: @JosephAdam you don't add this in the `favourite_post` view but in the view that retrieves your videos, the one that renders the template. You can typicall do it by overriding the `get_context_data` method.

Comment: @Daniel did not realize you edited the comment with the `get_context_data`, thanks managed to also make it work.

Comment: @Daniel it will be grand if you can provide the documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a template filter like:

```
@register.filter
def is_bookmarked(video, user):
    return user.fav_videos.filter(id=video.id).exists()
```

And then use it in your template like:

```
{% if detail|is_bookmarked:user %}
```

Comment: Presumably there is a many-to-many relationship here, so this won't work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman we won't know unless he shows us the models. But if it were the case then perhaps he should change the model.

Comment: @andreihondrari the `is_bookmarked` is not appearing in my template, now can I pass it from the views.py to the template ?

Comment: You need to load the python module from the `templatetags` directory into your template like `{% load your_module_name_only %}` as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)

Comment: @andreihondrari thanks for the documentation link! This worked out nicely for me.

Comment: @JosephAdam though I think that Daniel's answer is better, because with his technique you hit the database only once, whereas in my answer you hit the database multiple times (multiplied by the number of videos in the table). Do make sure to mark one of the answers as the correct one, to help other users identify the answer to your question.

Comment: @andreihondrari loved your approach with the documentation, now I understood tempalate tags after reading your answer